# How to filter data from model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    something = models.TextField[...]

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    other_something = models.TextField[...]
    ref = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
```

And I want to write function in ModelOne which return me all related objects from ModelTwo.

It's important: In ModelOne.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke [`self.modeltwo_set.all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/).